# Watch App: [WCSession defaultSession].isReachable is always retrieve 'FALSE' status on background app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, watchkit, wcsession

I am developing apple watch application. when app on foreground it is working fine `[WCSession defaultSession].isReachable` and retrieve `ON` status. Now my watch application is goes to background mode then problem must be create.

so how to resolve this issues? and retrieve `ON` status on background mode.

My code is as follows.

```
- (void)willActivate {

    [super willActivate];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.locationManager requestLocation];


    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }

    if ([[WCSession defaultSession] isReachable]) {
        NSLog(@"Session Reachable");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Session Not Reachable");

    }

    if([WCSession defaultSession].iOSDeviceNeedsUnlockAfterRebootForReachability) {

        WKAlertAction *action = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                     style:WKAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^{
                                                   }];

        NSString *title = @"My App";
        NSString *message = @"Reachability in the Watch app requires the paired iOS device to have been unlocked at least once after reboot";
        [self presentAlertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert actions:@[action]];
    }

    if ([[WCSession defaultSession] isReachable]) {
        NSString *strUserId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                           stringForKey:@"user_id"];
        if ([strUserId isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            WKAlertAction *act = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:WKAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(void){
            NSLog(@"ALERT YES ");
            }];

            NSArray *testing = @[act];

            [self presentAlertControllerWithTitle:@"My App" message:@"You are not login" preferredStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert actions:testing];

        }else{
            [self addTrackingdata];
            [self loadPairList];
        }
    }


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(UpdateData) name:@"refreshData" object:nil];


    ExtensionDelegate *del = (ExtensionDelegate *)[WKExtension sharedExtension].delegate;
    if (del.strReminderTime == 0 && del.isTimerFlag) {
        [self UpdateData];
        isReminderFlag = NO;
        del.isTimerFlag = NO;
        NSTimer * CheckTimer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(CheckConnectation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [CheckTimer fire];
    }



}

- (void)CheckConnectation
{
    WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    if([WCSession isSupported]) {
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];
    }

    if([WCSession defaultSession].isReachable){
        [_lblPairedStatus setText:@"connected"];
    }
    else
    {
        [_lblPairedStatus setText:@"disconnected"];
    }
}
```

Appreciate if any suggestion or idea.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. The solution for me was to check `isReachable` in the `didAppear` function instead of `willActivate`.

Comment: i was using on didAppear but it's not work on background mode.